# Is it possible to store invalid UTF-8 byte sequences in a postgres text column?

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

The encoding of my postgres database is UTF-8. In a certain table I have a [`text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) column into which I would like to insert some data. Now, the data is *mostly* valid UTF-8, but there are a number of instances of invalid byte sequences which I do *not* want to remove or substitute. My question is, is there any way of inserting the data into the `text` column without removing or substituting its invalid byte sequences?

Here's a simple example, executed from the shell (bash) command-line courtesy of [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

```
psql main postgres <<<"create table t1 (a text); insert into t1 (a) values (E'a\xC0b');";
## CREATE TABLE
## ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc0 0x62
```

I know this is probably a long shot, but is there any way of disabling postgres's validation of inserted text, perhaps on an ad hoc basis? I don't see how it would trouble postgres to have some byte sequences in `text` column data that happen to not be valid for the database's configured character encoding.

If this is not possible, I guess the only recourse is to store the data as straight binary data using the [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html) data type, but please let me know if there's a better solution out there.

Comment: AFAIK `text` always has an encoding (otherwise the database wouldn't know how to convert the bytes to characters, especially with variable length encodings such as UTF-8). If you just have a stream of bytes then you have `bytea` data, not `text`. Of course, things like `length` will work differently (compare `length('µ')` and `length('µ'::bytea)` for an example) so you're left with a choice of which pain you want to suffer.

Comment: No idea why the downvotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to store invalidly encoded data, use `bytea`. As mu alludes to, you'll have to deal with the fact that substrings and lengths etc are now byte-oriented, not character-oriented.

It *is* a problem to have invalidly encoded text. How would `left(n)` know how many characters to grab? How would indexing determine a correct lexical sort order? etc. Not to mention that PostgreSQL can't do on the fly character encoding conversion (e.g. `client_encoding = 'latin-1'`) if you have badly encoded data in a table.

You seem to want some kind of lax or forgiving mode for encodings, where it falls back to byte-based interpretation if the data isn't valid in the current encoding, or replaces it with `?` or something. That's a valid thing to want, but is not supported by PostgreSQL.